# Ограничить ввод текста в Text Field

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Мне нужно чтоб вводилось 40 символов если в Label.text = 40, а если в label.text = 70, то 70.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)Otpravit1 shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
if ([nastrLab6.text isEqualToString: @"40"]) {
NSUInteger newLength = [_Label.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
return (newLength >; 40) ? NO : YES;
}
if ([nastrLab6.text isEqualToString: @"70"]) {
NSUInteger newLength = [_Label.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
return (newLength >; 70) ? NO : YES;
}}
```

Вот у меня пример уже есть, Но ругается на "}}" :( и еще я не могу вводить в других TextField, если этот достиг придела..

Вот рабочий вариант:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber *number=[formatter numberFromString: _label.text];
    int maxL=number.intValue;
    if(textField.text.length>maxL && string.length==0)
        return YES;
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > maxL) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Comment: Что за бред? я не могу даже в уме это скомплилировать... Что это за конструкция >; ????
Где участие самого TextField`a Otpravit1?? 
Блин весь код бред.
Давайте еще раз перефразируем ТЗ. Что именно надо?

Comment: нужно чтоб был лимит ввода текста в TextField, но этот лимит был такой, какой написан в label.text.

Comment: Ура, нашла, уже не надо =) а скажите пожалуйста Bimawa, нужно чтоб при оплате, в label менялось число (это как покупка денег в играх).

Comment: Вот это лучше уже.

Comment: Код немножко не корректен.

Answer (score 1):

В общем UIVIew классы имеют свойство tag, благодаря ему мы может дать уникальный идентификатор Вью элемента, в данном случае TextView`a.  Метод же

```
textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
```

дергается всегда, как только меняется какой либо из TextField и именно тот который меняет свое значение выводится в поле Otpravit1, в Вашем случае. Получаем тэг, проверяем его на второе ли это поле или первое, если же второе. Запрашиваем у первого значение text  и вот уже потом проверяем количество введеных символов и ретурним YES or NO. Позже кину кусочек кода.

Comment: Я уже сделала кодик)) выставила в вопросе его) помоги с этим вопросом пожалуйста "нужно чтоб при оплате, в label менялось число (это как покупка денег в играх)."

Comment: а нам кто то по -1 дал(((

Comment: ну [label setText:@"123123"];

Comment: У Вас минусик убрал ) надеюсь больше ни кто не поставит )

Comment: Спасибо) ну мне же надо чтоб только после оплаты, будет кнопка на которую нажимаешь и там происходит оплата, и если платеж прошел, то label.text = @"1000";, например) Как в играх на айфонах деньги покупать)

Comment: Ааа ну это уже другой вопрос и лучше создать новый топик.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас создам.